# TypeScript concat overload issue

Tags: typescript

I have given the link below to TS playground (TS 3.8.3) where I tried to concat two arrays with different initial values using the .concat() function. TypeScript is returning an error which I think in simple words is "You are trying to concat two arrays but the type of the resultant array is assumed to be of array 1, so include array 1 properties in array 2".

Is there any specific way we can tackle this issue, given that the properties are generated on runtime for both the arrays ?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.8.3#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po%20rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc%20VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtajBdw0VBkPAAeWkACtQABeUAAbQA3hRuPlQABGAC%20vG5vNAACZBQBdADclMgNAQ5nxDOZbK5DGYkHy4oADMLOZrtaAAMz6qXymhmYRsmn0pkBJWwfEACidKqZAEo5YolYJ4O4AtB4MwXdbvcUcA0PGQvIh4AMGCD2NT7oxOMx2Eb%20LBoOpEkn4HoRF4AEQAUVWDEQNX0paSONL4AcqAA5MIAHKQCSloIqOnfMi7QSQfha46oRwKVzSPCgJzxnSjLD6FAIRAw4RXb6SBPREQGDg47osNhcbhBEpAA)

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure why you trying to concat two really different type of array, but if you really have to do it, then try doing

```
let tryObj: Record<string, number>[] = [{id: 1},{id: 2}];

let concatObj: Record<string, number>[] = [{age:20},{age: 30}]

let ans = tryObj.concat(concatObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let ans = [].concat(arr1,arr2)
```